# The charge given by a commutator

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, charge, commutator

I saw in the text that

$$[Q,X]=cX$$

and says the operator $X$ has charge $c$ under the generator $Q$.
I tried to understand why the coefficient $c$ means the charge. So I used this relation to get the result(using the property of $e^{a}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{a}{n})^{n}$)

$$e^{iQ} X e^{-iQ}=e^{ic}X$$

which seems like the commutator really shows the charge of the operator $X$ as $c$. Is it right way to understand the statement?

Comment: It is not quite clear what your question is. Could you perhaps try to elaborate your question a bit? Do you want help with the physical interpretation of the math?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $[Q,X] = cX$?

Comment: Yes, your final equation is right. It follows from the standard so-called "Hadamard lemma" [combinatoric identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma).

Comment: What you've provided is the definition of what we mean by charge, so i'm not sure what else you're trying to understand. You can't go any deeper than the definition

Answer (score 1):

If $Q|q\rangle = q|q\rangle$, then
$$
Q(X|q\rangle)= (QX-XQ+XQ)|q\rangle= ([Q,X] +Xq)|q\rangle=(c+q)X|q\rangle.
$$
So applying $X$ to an eigenstate $|q\rangle$ of $Q$ increases the eigenvalue, or "charge," by $c$. We can  say that $X$ is giving a charge $c$ to $|q\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that we transform in proportion to such commutators to produce a symmetry. It may help to discuss an example that's a little more complicated than what you've described.

The infinitesimal BRST transformation $X\mapsto X+\delta X$ is a symmetry of the BRST-quantised Yang-Mills Lagrangian. The BRST operator $Q$ (also called the BRST charge) satisfies $\delta b=\theta [Q,\,b],\,\delta f=\theta\{ Q,\,f\}$ for an infinitesimal constant Grassmann number $\theta$, with arbitrary bosonic field $b$ and fermionic field $f$. The need for anticommutators with fermions comes from $Q$ being fermionic (which is why $\theta$ needs to be a Grassmann number to make $\delta$ bosonic); if $Q$ were bosonic, in which case we wouldn't be discussing the BRST example, it'd be commutators all the way.

We can verify $\delta(XY)=(\delta X)Y+X\delta Y$ for fields $X,\,Y$ of definite exchange symmetry, and $\delta$ commutes with $\partial_\mu$.